# Change datatables to show info on a multiline row

Tags: jquery, datatables

Looking at this example [Datatables zero configuration example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)

How can I change the code so that the first column will is displaying info spread over 2 lines ?

So "Airi" on line 1 and "Satou" on line 2 ?

Comment: Put `Airi<br>Satou` in the cell.

Comment: Is there a way to fix the cell width so text will be multi line ?

Comment: I googled "datatables column width" and this is what popped up: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width

Answer (score 0):

The easiest ways I can think of:
Change the CSS of the column to a size that should will force line breaks
Put in a linebreak to force it by hand(add br)

The best practice way is to have them in two separate columns though.  Datatables allows you to specify sorting of the initial column, and then sort by the second (so even if the same last name, still sorting by the first name)